# Count image by date for each userId in mongoDB and map response with user emailId

Tags: mongodb

I have two collection named User and ImageDetail.

I need to find image count by date for each user, and response list should contain user email Id with userId.

**Collection Data**:

**ImageDetail collection**

```
[
   {
     useId: 'A1',
     images: [
       {date: '01/02/2018', image: 'image1'},
       {date: '01/02/2018', image: 'image2'},
       {date: '02/02/2018', image: 'image3'},
    ]
  },
  {
     useId: "A2",
     images: [
       {date: '01/02/2018', image: 'image4'},
       {date: '02/02/2018', image: 'image5'},
       {date: '02/02/2018', image: 'image6'},
       {date: '03/02/2018', image: 'image7'},
     ]
  }
]
```

**User collection**:

```
    [
       {
         userId: 'A1',
         emailId: 'user1@gmail.com',
       },
       {
         userId: 'A2',
         emailId: 'user2@gmail.com',
       }
     ]
```

**Looking for output**:

```
[
   {
     userId: 'A1',
     emailId: 'user1@gmail.com',
     images: [
       {date: '01/02/2018', count: '2'}.
       {date: '02/02/2018', count: '1'}.
     ],
   },
   {
     userId: 'A2',
     emailId: 'user2@gmail.com',
     images: [
       {date: '01/02/2018', count: '1'}.
       {date: '02/02/2018', count: '2'}.
       {date: '03/02/2018', count: '1'}.
     ],
   }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this aggregation:

```
db.getCollection("ImageDetail").aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$images"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {date: "$images.date", userId: "$userId"},
            count: {$sum: 1},
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.userId",
            images: {$push: {date: "$_id.date", count: "$count"}}
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "user",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "userId",
            as: "$match"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$match"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            images: "$images",
            userId: "$_id",
            email: "$match.emailId"
        }
    }
])
```